# How do you show the flex handCursor in firefox 4?

Tags: apache-flex, user-controls, adobe, label, firefox4

Hey guys, I'm having a problem with the handCursor component in Flex and Firefox 4.

I've followed the code [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/11/18/displaying-a-hand-cursor-when-mousing-over-a-flex-control/) to create my handCursor, but it won't render the hand on either my demo or the flex docs. Has anyone found a way to show the handCursor in FF4? If not, what's the best way to handle creating a similar paradigm?

**Edit**: Here's the code used on both the demo site above, and in a test case I've drawn up locally. Works in all but FF4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
        <mx:Form styleName="plain">
            <mx:FormItem label="useHandCursor:">
                <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox1" selected="true" />
            </mx:FormItem>
            <mx:FormItem label="buttonMode:">
                <mx:CheckBox id="checkBox2" selected="true" />
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

    <mx:Image id="img"
            source="http://www.helpexamples.com/flash/images/image1.jpg"
            useHandCursor="{checkBox1.selected}"
            buttonMode="{checkBox2.selected}" />

</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Code's posted. It's also on the link, with an interactive demo you can test right now. No difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why its not working in FF4 and didnt checked it, Try to add attribute **mouseChildren** in IMAGE

```
mouseChildren="true"
```

hopes that work

Comment: Bringing this back from the dead. This works in all browsers outside of FF4-- this was a browser bug. Should this behavior re-appear in other cases, this is how it gets fixed.